# JVM Security Manager File permissions - custom policy

Tags: java, jvm, securitymanager, java-security-manager

I've found a somehow unexpected behaviour using JVM Security Manager custom policies.

repo: https://github.com/pedrorijo91/jvm-sec-manager

in branch master, go into the `/code` folder:

- custom policy file grants File read permission for file `../allow/allow.txt`
- no permission for the file `../deny/deny.txt`
- the code in the HelloWorld.java tries to read both files
- There's a `run.sh` script to run the command

Now everything works as expected: the allowed file reads, but the other throws a security exception: `java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "../deny/deny.txt" "read")`

But if I move both files (`../allow/allow.txt` and `../deny/deny.txt`) to the `code` folder (changing the custom policy and the java code to use those files), I get no exception. (branch 'unexpected')

Is the current directory a special case or something else is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Brief explanation

This behaviour is documented in a number of places:

- [`FilePermission`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FilePermission.html)'s overview;
- the [Permissions in the JDK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html#FilePermission) document; and
- the [`URLClassLoader#getPermissions(CodeSource)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#getPermissions-java.security.CodeSource-) method.

The latter two reiterate the closing note of the first one, which states that:

> Code can always read a file from the same directory it's in (or a subdirectory of that directory); it does not need explicit permission to do so.

In other words, if

```
(HelloWorld.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().implies(
    new CodeSource(new URL("file:" + codeDir),
    (Certificate[]) null)) == true)
```

then `HelloWorld` will by default be granted read access to the denoted directory and its descendants. Particularly for the `code` directory *itself* this should make some intuitive sense, as otherwise the class would be unable to even access `public`-access classes within its very package.

#### The full story

It is basically up to the `ClassLoader`: If it [statically](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html#getPermissions--) assigned any `Permission`s to the `ProtectionDomain` to which it [mapped](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass-java.lang.String-byte:A-int-int-java.security.ProtectionDomain-) the class--which applies to both `java.net.URLClassLoader` and `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader` (the OpenJDK-specific default system class loader)--these permissions will always be accorded to the domain, regardless of the `Policy` in effect.

#### Workarounds

The typical "quick-n'-dirty" workaround to anything authorization-related is to extend `SecurityManager` and override the methods irking you; i.e. in this case the `checkRead` group of methods.

For a more thorough solution that doesn't reduce the flexibility of `AccessController` and friends, on the other hand, you would have to write a class loader that at the very least overrides `URLClassLoader#getPermissions(CodeSource)` and/or restricts loaded classes' domains' `CodeSource`s down to the file level (code sources of domains assigned by default by `URLClassLoader` and `AppClassLoader` imply (recursively) the .class file's classpath entry (JAR or directory)). For further granularity, your loader might as well assign instances of your own domain subclass, and/or domains encapsulating code sources of your own subclass, overriding respectively `ProtectionDomain#implies(Permission)` and/or `CodeSource#implies(CodeSource)`; the former could for example be made to support "negative permission" semantics, and the latter could base code source implication on arbitrary logic, potentially decoupled from physical code location (think e.g. "trust levels").

---

#### Clarification as per the comments

To prove that under a different class loader these permissions actually matter, consider the following example: There are two classes, `A` and `B`; `A` has the `main` method, which simply calls a method on `B`. Additionally, the application is launched using a different system class loader, which a) assigns domains on a per-class basis (rather than on a per-classpath-entry basis, as is the default) to classes it loads, without b) assigning any permissions to these domains.

**Loader:**

```
package com.example.q45897574;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.CodeSource;
import java.security.PermissionCollection;
import java.security.Permissions;
import java.security.PrivilegedAction;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RestrictiveClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

    private static final Pattern COMMON_SYSTEM_RESOURCE_NAMES = Pattern
            .compile("(((net\\.)?java)|(java(x)?)|(sun|oracle))\\.[a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-_\\$\\.]+");
    private static final String OWN_CLASS_NAME = RestrictiveClassLoader.class.getName();
    private static final URL[] EMPTY_URL_ARRAY = new URL[0], CLASSPATH_ENTRY_URLS;
    private static final PermissionCollection NO_PERMS = new Permissions();

    static {
        String[] classpathEntries = AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<String>() {
            @Override
            public String run() {
                return System.getProperty("java.class.path");
            }
        }).split(File.pathSeparator);
        Set<URL> classpathEntryUrls = new LinkedHashSet<>(classpathEntries.length, 1);
        for (String classpathEntry : classpathEntries) {
            try {
                URL classpathEntryUrl;
                if (classpathEntry.endsWith(".jar")) {
                    classpathEntryUrl = new URL("file:jar:".concat(classpathEntry));
                }
                else {
                    if (!classpathEntry.endsWith("/")) {
                        classpathEntry = classpathEntry.concat("/");
                    }
                    classpathEntryUrl = new URL("file:".concat(classpathEntry));
                }
                classpathEntryUrls.add(classpathEntryUrl);
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            }
        }
        CLASSPATH_ENTRY_URLS = classpathEntryUrls.toArray(EMPTY_URL_ARRAY);
    }

    private static byte[] readClassData(URL classResource) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(classResource.openStream());
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                out.write(in.read());
            }
            return out.toByteArray();
        }
    }

    public RestrictiveClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(EMPTY_URL_ARRAY, parent);
        for (URL classpathEntryUrl : CLASSPATH_ENTRY_URLS) {
            addURL(classpathEntryUrl);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if (name == null) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException("< null >", new NullPointerException("name argument must not be null."));
        }
        if (OWN_CLASS_NAME.equals(name)) {
            return RestrictiveClassLoader.class;
        }
        if (COMMON_SYSTEM_RESOURCE_NAMES.matcher(name).matches()) {
            return getParent().loadClass(name);
        }
        Class<?> ret = findLoadedClass(name);
        if (ret != null) {
            return ret;
        }
        return findClass(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        String modifiedClassName = name.replace(".", "/").concat(".class");
        URL classResource = findResource(modifiedClassName);
        if (classResource == null) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
        }
        byte[] classData;
        try {
            classData = readClassData(classResource);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException(name, ioe);
        }
        return defineClass(name, classData, 0, classData.length, constructClassDomain(classResource));
    }

    @Override
    protected PermissionCollection getPermissions(CodeSource codesource) {
        return NO_PERMS;
    }

    private ProtectionDomain constructClassDomain(URL codeSourceLocation) {
        CodeSource cs = new CodeSource(codeSourceLocation, (Certificate[]) null);
        return new ProtectionDomain(cs, getPermissions(cs), this, null);
    }

}
```

**`A`:**

```
package com.example.q45897574;

public class A {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        /*
         * Note:
         * > Can't we set the security manager via launch argument?
         * No, it has to be set here, or bootstrapping will fail.
         * > Why?
         * Because our class loader's domain is unprivileged.
         * > Can't it be privileged?
         * Yes, but then everything under the same classpath entry becomes
         * privileged too, because our loader's domain's code source--which
         * _its own_ loader creates, thus escaping our control--implies _the
         * entire_ classpath entry. There are various workarounds, which
         * however fall outside of this example's scope.
         */
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        B.b();
    }

}
```

**`B`**:

```
package com.example.q45897574;

public class B {

    public static void b() {
        System.out.println("success!");
    }
}
```

**Unprivileged test:**
Make sure *nothing* is granted at the policy level; then run (assuming a Linux-based OS--modify classpath as appropriate):

```
java -cp "/home/your_user/classpath/" \
-Djava.system.class.loader=com.example.q45897574.RestrictiveClassLoader \
-Djava.security.debug=access=failure com.example.q45897574.A
```

You should get a `NoClassDefFoundError`, along with a failed `FilePermission` for `com.example.q45897574.A`.

**Privileged test:**
Now grant the necessary permission to `A` (again make sure to correct both the codeBase (code source URL) and permission target name):

```
grant codeBase "file:/home/your_user/classpath/com/example/q45897574/A.class" {
    permission java.io.FilePermission "/home/your_user/classpath/com/example/q45897574/B.class", "read";
};
```

...and re-run. This time execution should complete successfully.

Comment: you say the code needs access to the directory and subdirectories, otherwise it couldn't access even public classes. But the security manager, manages the application runtime accesses, and the class is compiled by the compiler (who has access to the directories) and the .class files can me put into any custom folder the jvm can always access. So I think it's not a valid reason, or maybe my thoughts have some flaw? But of course it's kinda intuitive the code folder is included in the permissions, but the javadoc doesn't mention anything like that

Comment: The class loader doesn't blindly engage in privileged operations such as reading a .class file from the file system, unless the caller(s), including the class referencing the to-be-loaded class, actually have read access to that file. Run your app with `-Djava.security.debug=access=failure` to confirm all the `FilePermission` evaluations occurring during class loading. As for the documentation, this behavior is briefly mentioned in `URLClassLoader`'s overview, which states that instances "inherit" the `AccessControlContext` of their creators, when loading classes / resources.

Comment: To prove my point (that a class won't be able to access another class, even if public and in its package, unless granted access to read its .class file) I've appended an example to my answer. Hope it clears things up a bit.