# Is it possible to limit file access of certain classes to a certain directory?

Tags: java

I am creating a plugin system which dynamically loads classes, and since the plugins are user created, I want to restrict their access to everywhere but a working directory. Is there a solution for this in Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically the JVM offers the [Security manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/smPortGuide.html) architecture.

One part of that are [FilePermissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897574/jvm-security-manager-file-permissions-custom-policy), which enable some sort of control here.

But note: this is really an advanced topic, and easy to get wrong, but your primary use case of *isolating* plugins coming from different packages should be doable.